# Programming a button with javascript using outer files

Tags: javascript, html

Hey guys im trying to program a button in javascript, I called a the button when the button is clicked but it doesnt seem to work. any help would be great. Thanks (this is my first time asking a question so please forgive if my format isnt correct. )

// HTML

```html
<div>
  <button onclick = "page"  > Test button </button>
< /div>
```

// Javascript

```js
function page () {
  <input type="button" onclick="location.href='https://google.com';" 
        value="Go to Google" />
}
```

Comment: What gave you the idea that you can use HTML inside Javascript? And even if that were possible (which it is in JSX), what are you hoping for that to do? What do you mean by *outer files*?

Comment: yeah sorry, this is the first time I integrate Js into html and I had trouble. By "outer files" i meant a reference link

Answer (score 1):

You need React to have HTML inside JavaScript in (more or less) the way you wrote it

It is also not recommended to have inline event handling (onclick etc)

You likely mean

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { // when elements on page are available
  document.getElementById('page').addEventListener('click', function() { // when button clicked
    location.href = "https://google.com";
  });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="page" type="button">Go to Google</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with just html if you don't want to use react

```html
<button onclick="window.location.replace('https://www.google.com')">
  Click Me
</button>
```

Comment: It is however not recommended to have inline event handling

Answer (score 0):

You can't just use plain HTML inside a vanilla JavaScript function.

With plain JS you can assign a DOM element Object to a variable and add an event listener that will trigger the function you create on click:

```
    const btn = document.querySelector("button");
   
    function redirectToGoogle () {
       window.location.replace('https://www.google.com')
    }

    btn.addEventListener('click', redirectToGoogle);
```

Answer (score 0):

***ANSWER***

1. In HTML file, you didn't call page function on button onclick event.
2. In JavaScript file, location.href is used to locate to another page when you are on the same page.

```js
function page() {
  location.href = "https://www.google.com/" ;
}
```

```html
<button onclick = "page()" >Test button</button>
```

Comment: It is however not recommended to have inline event handling

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).